# Router still sees RPi with old hostname

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, hostname

I am using a raspberry pi to do various things. I installed OS 1 on my RPi a few weeks ago, established a hostname (I THINK), call it hostname1. I used a wifi adapter to connect to the internet for it (although possibly ethernet for initial setup).

I later decided I wanted to do something else, requiring a different OS, OS2. I also changed the hostname to hostname2 because I'm a child and wanted to call it "CutiePi" (aka hostname2). Now, the weird thing is that when I plug my Pi in with OS2 loaded and what I assume is hostname2, my router shows it as having hostname1. I also decided to change the MAC address in /etc/network/interfaces, and the router would show the original MAC address and hostname1.

Can anyone explain this behavior? Is there something that a router sees on a device that is independent of the OS installed that might be confusing it?

Comment: Try restarting the router, it might just have the hostname cached

Comment: Many router renember MAC/hostname associations, e.g. to give it the same local IP address via DHCP. Also, many routers allow to edit/delete these associations. Look closely at the web interface of your router.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the mac address of the NIC with this command

```
ip link set address <MAC> <Device>
```

Example

```
ip link set address XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX eth0
```

---

To do this automatically whenever the interface is created (like at boot), create this file:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/70-mac-address.rules
```

Contents:

Note that X is the original mac address and Y is the new address.

Note that `/usr/bin/ip` may not be the path to the `ip` binary on all systems. To know where you `ip` binry is located, use the command `which ip` and change the the following accordingly.

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", ATTR{address}=="XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX", RUN+="/usr/bin/ip link set dev %k address YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY"
```

Comment: Ah, that works! Any way to change MAC addresses at boot? or well, have it persist between reboots?

Comment: A udev rule will be able to do that. I'll add it to answer.